# Replacing sometimes causes exceptions in unicode strings

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode, encoding

In the Python Unicode Howto, it says:

> Note that the arguments to these [string] methods can be Unicode strings or
> 8-bit strings. 8-bit strings will be converted to Unicode before
> carrying out the operation; Python’s default ASCII encoding will be
> used, so characters greater than 127 will cause an exception:
>
> `>>> s.find('Was\x9f')                    Traceback (most recent call last):`
>
> `... UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x9f in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)`
>
> `>>> s.find(u'Was\x9f')`
>
> `-1`

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

So you would assume a unicode string can use unicode strings in find/replace/count functions, but it looks like it's not that simple. Check this out in Python console:

```
>>> type(u'hi')
<type 'unicode'>
>>> type('i')
<type 'str'>
>>> type('mÑ')
<type 'str'>
>>> u'hi'.replace('i','m')
u'hm'
>>> u'hi'.replace('i','mÑ')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> 'hi'.replace('i','mÑ')
'hm\xc3\x91'
```

So, would the best way to properly replace such replacement in any type of string be an if else case with all str values, or all u'values' if str(type(input)) has 'unicode'?

And what's worse, this seems to not do anything at all with or without the 'u' before string:

```
print((u"<head><script>%s</script>" % (thevariable,))
```

but only when I use `from __future__ import unicode_literals` ??

Comment: The best way is to use python 3 where everything is Unicode. Just saying!

Comment: I recommend avoiding stuff like `'mÑ'` in Python 2. If you want Unicode literal strings in your code then always use proper Unicode strings like  `u'mÑ'` (and of course you need a proper coding directive at the top of the script). Yes, the Python 2 methods will work with plain strings or Unicode strings, but it can get very confusing if you mix them together. And as Rahul said, Unicode handling is much saner in Python 3, where there's a clear distinction between byte strings and text strings.

Comment: In the mean time, you may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: Thanks, I think if/else for unicode seems to work in the odd case of a downloaded string and a replacement string from a file I have.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of `u'hi'.replace('i','mÑ')` you have a Unicode string, so replace needs Unicode strings.  Both were byte strings, so they were converted using the default `ascii` codec, and `Ñ` is not ASCII.

In the case of `'hi'.replace('i','mÑ')` you have a byte string, so replace needs byte strings.  That's what you gave it, so it works.  In Python 2.7, byte strings with non-ASCII are encoded in the source encoding, so I expect you have a `#coding:utf8` at the top of the script and saved the source in UTF-8 given that `\xc3\x91` is UTF-8 for `Ñ`.

Python 3 forbids non-ASCII characters in byte string constants (you can still embed hexadecimal escapes, e.g. `b'm\xc3\x91'`, but `b'mÑ'` will give an error) and does not do implicit encode/decode when the wrong type is used, so it helps cleanly separate the problem.